# Slim v4 Creating Log File

Tags: php, debugging, logging, frameworks, slim

So, my issue is that I'm having trouble to make Slim record all its actions inside a file (for example : app.log). I ran across a lot of tutorials and other forum similar to this one but the issue was that they were using the v3 of the Slim Framework.
I saw some post suggesting things like this inside a settings.php :

```
return [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true, // set to false in production
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false, // Allow the web server to send the content-length header
        // Renderer settings
        'renderer' => [
            'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/',
        ],
        // Monolog settings
        'logger' => [
            'name' => 'my-app',
            'path' => __DIR__ . '/../logs/' . $logDate->format('Y-m-d') . 'app.log',
        ],
    ],
];
```

But the issue with that method is that, well, settings aren't set up this way anymore in v4. So here I am. Stuck. If anybody could give me a hand, it'll help a lot !

Comment: Settings are still the same in Slim 4, you simply load the settings within a container definition. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a log file which contains all the activities made by the app and store it in a "app.log" file. How can I achieve that ? How can I load the settings within a container ?

Answer (score 0):

To load the settings within a container you have to add a container definition for it.

Example settings file: `config/settings.php`

```php
return [
    // set to false in production
    'displayErrorDetails' => true,

    // Renderer settings
    'renderer' => [
        'template_path' => __DIR__ . '/../templates/',
    ],
    // Monolog settings
    'logger' => [
        'name' => 'my-app',
        'path' => __DIR__ . '/../logs/' . date('Y-m-d') . '_app.log',
     ],
];
```

Example container entry in `config/container.php`:

```php
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
// ...

return [
    // ...

    'settings' => function () {
        return require __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
    },

   // Add more entries here ...
}
```

To fetch the settings within the container use this:

```php
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
// ...

return [
    // ...

    LoggerInterface::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
        $settings = $container->get('settings');
        $name = $settings['logger']['name'];

        $logger = new Logger($name);
        // Add logger handler...

        return $logger;
    },

    // ...
}
```

Tip: For autowiring support it's better to use an collection object instead of an simple "string" as container identifier. [Read more](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html#configuration)